# Is it legal for a standard algorithm comparator to accept objects of different types?

Tags: c++, c++11

[An answer recently posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22457695/700825) showed code that provides, to a standard algorithm, a comparator taking operands of different types:

> ### 2. Use a comparator with templated `operator()`.
>
> Instead of using a lambda, define a functor with a templated `operator()`.
>
> ```
> struct comparator
> {
>     template<typename T, typename U>
>     bool operator()(T const& lhs, U const& rhs) const {
>         return lhs.mCommonField < rhs.mCommonField;
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> Then, it's as easy as:
>
> ```
> std::sort(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(), comparator{});
> std::sort(bStructs.begin(), bStructs.end(), comparator{});
> // ...
> std::set_intersection(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
>                       bStructs.begin(), bStructs.end(),
>                       std::back_inserter(intersection),
>                       comparator{}
>                       );
> ```
>
> Just note that as there is a template in the comparator, it must be declared outside of function scope. Live example on [Coliru Viewer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a673d5061e58c7b4).

Apparently this at least works in practice, as evidenced by the working live demo.

But is it strictly allowed by the standard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The corresponding section in the standard is §25.4. The only requirements on the type of the `Compare` parameter are in §25.4/2:

> `Compare` is a function object type. The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type `Compare`, when contextually converted to `bool`, yields `true` if the first argument of the call is less than the second, and `false` otherwise. `Compare comp` is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation. It is assumed that `comp` will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.

In other words, when called, it can't change the values pointed at by the iterators and should yield a strict weak ordering on the values. Since that comparator satisfies both of these requirements, yes, it's legal!

In fact, this kind of comparison functor is exactly what is proposed in [N3421 - Making Operator Functors `greater<>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm), now part of the C++14 standard. It provides `void` specializations for the standard library functors that perfect forward comparisons to the corresponding operator, if any. For example (taken from the proposal paper):

```
namespace std
{
    template <> struct greater<void> {
      template <class T, class U> auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const
        -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) > std::forward<U>(u))
           { return std::forward<T>(t) > std::forward<U>(u); }
    };
}
```

Comment: 25.4 paragraph 2 is not section 25.4.2 (which describes `std::nth_element`).  Around here we often write 25.4/2 or 25.4p2.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about the proper notation. I'll have to go back and fix past answers, too.